# How to save stacktrace before application crash

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to store and send crash log to server. I am able to save crash log in preference before it exists, but the problem is that it restarts the application and does not display the default crash message to user.

I want the crash flow for user to be normal.

```
public void registerCrash(){

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
        }
    });
}


public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
{
    thread.getStackTrace();
    saveDataToFile(e.toString());
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

If i change the `System.exits(0)`, it abruptly crashes, and does not save any log in file, and with `System.exit(-1);`, it restarts the application on crash.

**Edit**

saveDateToFile()

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences(CRASH_LOG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
prefsEditor.putString(STACK_TRACE, data);
prefsEditor.apply();
```

Comment: Why not using Fabric (Crashlytics) or similar? They also restart an application after crash to get an error log.

Comment: @CoolMind , we need to send crash report to our end point as well.

Comment: can you show saveDataToFile()?

Comment: @ligi : I have updated my question

Comment: I think using shared perferences here might be the problem. When developing tracedroid I had similar tings - what you are in that uncaught state you wan to do things that have less ties to the system and fast. Just try to write a plain file or just use tracedroid collection mechanism

Answer (score 1):

use [Fabric](https://fabric.io/) to get crash report and many more like Installs or event etc.

it will automatically sent the crash reportto the server and let you know via email.

easy to implement, just need to include sdk [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html)

Comment: u wanna save exceptions ?

Comment: Yes, I want to, and I am able to save exceptions, but with `  System.exit(-1);` it restarts the application on crash

Comment: crash is something which is call unhandled exception! which can be traced by fabric. and the exception which is handled u can use it trace is by exception.printStackTrace();

Comment: System.exit(0);// normal termination - Successful - zero
System.exit(-1);//Exit with some Error
System.exit(1);//one or any positive integer // exit with some Information message

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://github.com/ligi/tracedroid - it can collect the crash-logs for you and you can write your own sending module